# wxHaskell on win7, can't find wxc.dll or .so

Tags: haskell, wxhaskell

I have installed wxwidget and wxhaskell(using cabal) on windows7
and I made a test.hs

```
import Graphics.UI.WX

main :: IO ()
main = start gui

gui :: IO ()
gui = do f <- frame [text := "Hello"]
         inp <- entry f []
         out <- entry f []
         but <- button f [ text := "Hello"
                        , on command := do s <- get inp text;
                                           set out [text := "Hello "++s]
                         ]
         set f [ layout := floatCentre $ column 5
                            [ label "What is your name?"
                            , widget inp
                            , widget but
                            , widget out
                            ] ]
```

and then I load and run test.hs in winGHCi, and here is output

```
"ghci> " :load "test.hs"
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
"ghci> " main
can't load .so/.DLL for: C:\Users\zhaijy\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.10.2\wxc-0.92.1.1-2q6ESjcRWaMHNPxrdblcRv\wxc.dll (addDLL: could not load DLL)
"ghci> "
```

I can't figure out how to solve this problem. What do I need to do/add/change so the DLL could be loaded?

Answer (score 1):

This is a GHCi bug; it is solved in GHC 7.10.3